# ActiveAdmin - Custom Javascript only for specific resource, not for any page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, customization, activeadmin

I'm not an ActiveAdmin expert. 
I need to have a number of customizations on some index pages. As recommended in the documentation, I'm trying to maintain AA pages build and then customize them by using Javascript.
I succeeded by putting my own Javascript file under app/assets/javascripts, and then appending

```
//=require my_javascript_file
```

to app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js

The problem is that this way the Javascript code gets loaded for ANY index page of any model.
Which is the best way to insert Javascript code only for a specific model?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Can you just add `javascript_include_tag "my_javascript_file"` on the relevant page template?  I don't see what ActiveAdmin has to do with this, though i might be misunderstanding you.

Comment: @MaxWilliams you are correct if you need page specific js or css you have to include it in view

Comment: The thing is I'm not using classic RoR views, I'm just using ActiveAdmin to build the pages, i.e.
`app/admin/my_model.rb:`

`ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do`
[Arbre code]
`end`

Said this, I tried using the command
`script :src => javascript_path('my_javascript_file.js'), :type => "text/javascript"`
to include the Javascript file in the page, but with no luck

Answer (score 7):

For me worked following:

```
form do |f|
  text_node javascript_include_tag "path_to/my_javascript_file"
...
```

Comment: Note that path should be relative to `app/assets/javascripts` folder + add it to `assets.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following worked well in my case. I added the following to config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
sub_folder = 'page_assets'
specific_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'javascripts', sub_folder).to_path
Dir.glob("#{specific_assets_path}/*.{js,coffee}").entries.each { |file|
  asset = "#{sub_folder}/#{File.basename(file, File.extname(file))}.js"
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [ asset ]
}
```

Then I put my js and coffee files in app/assets/javascript/page_assets
e.g my_page.coffee

Now in my view I add:

```
<%=
  javascript_include_tag 'page_assets/my_page'
%>
```

My view is an html.erb partial, but the same should work for a page that is defined in the my_page.rb file.

My active_admin.js just requires the active_admin base, because I don't want the active_admin asset to include all my per-page scripts:

```
//= require active_admin/base
```

The advantage of this mechanism is that I don't need to remember to add to the precompile list when I add a new per-page script - it's done automatically. ActiveAdmin won't add my page_assets scripts to the active_admin.js main asset (because I haven't got require_tree . in active_admin.js)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @Alexandr's answer,

1. Add below line under form do loop as:

   form do |f|
   text_node javascript_include_tag "path_to/my_javascript_file"
   end
2. Add `path_to/my_javascript_file` in `confg/initializers/assets.rb` to precompile it.
3. Add

   `//= link path_to/my_javascript_file.js`

   to `assets/config/manifest.js`