# Rails Active Admin + Chartkick = Not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, chartkick

I was trying to use Chartkick to generate graph that shows on rails active admin dashboard. Here is the tutorial I am using: http://www.patrickedelman.com/simple-charting-for-activeadmin/

However, the graph did not show up, instead, it shows "Loading..."

I already include javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" and gem chartkick is installed, but it still does not work.

Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't forget to add `#= require chartkick` to `active_admin.js.coffee`.

To render a chart in AA dashboard, go with:

```
div class: 'custom-class' do
  h3 'Your name for a chart'
  @metric = Model.group(:attribute).count # whatever data you pass to chart
  render partial: 'metrics/partial_name', locals: {metric: @metric}
end
```

This file

```
partial: 'metrics/partial_name'
```

lays under `app/views/metrics/partial_name` directory, and could have the following structure:

`_partial_name.html.haml`:

```
= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick"
= pie_chart metric
```

Having this you should be ok with using chartkick.

Comment: for googlechart; javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"

Answer (score 7):

#### For Active Admin on Rails 6

After add the gem "chartkick", you need to add to app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js:

```
//= require chartkick
//= require Chart.bundle
```

Comment: This is the actual fix for Rails 6. Tried many other stuff and this is the only one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the js in the active admin file without rendering a partial, you can do this:

```
text_node javascript_include_tag 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js', skip_pipeline: true
```

In my case I have a custom page and I added it in the content block

```
content do
  text_node javascript_include_tag 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js', skip_pipeline: true

  columns do
    column do
      xxxx
    end
  end
end
```

I got the idea from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61460749/3984542

Answer (score 0):

**For Active Admin on Rails 7**

I added the following lines to my `active_admin.rb` (I'm using Highcharts):

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.register_javascript "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"
  config.register_javascript "chartkick.js"
end
```